# Improving the performance

Tags: java, algorithm

How do I improve the performance of the code I wrote below to handle the following problem.

**N is the number of object in a circle. I start at `0` and take `M` jumps, visiting each object in a circle. If a object is repeated then i will stop and number of object visited is my answer**

**Current code**

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
 import java.util.*;

// you can use System.out.println for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int N, int M) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

       int answer =1;
       HashMap<Integer , Integer> som = new HashMap<>();
       boolean check = true;
       int x =0;
       som.put(0,0);
       while(check){
            int  m = (x+ M) % N ;
            x = m;
            if(som.containsKey(x))
                check = false;
            else{
                som.put(x,0);
                answer++;
            }
       }
       return answer;
    }
```

t's not good for 10^6 size number

Comment: Why are you using a `HashMap`?

Comment: just to check the visited points

Comment: [check this](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoGK6AW9-Z4U/)

Comment: This question is more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. From http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas...

    Best practices and design pattern usage
    Security issues
    **Performance**
    Correctness in unanticipated cases

Comment: What the algorithm name ? please more explanation needed ?

Comment: How large can N be? If N <= 10^6 then this algorithm is perfectly fine O(N).

Answer (score 3):

If you factorise N and M into prime factors (i.e. N = p[1]^e[1] * p[2]^e[2] * ... and M = p[1]^f[1] * p[2]^f[2] ...) and consider their exponents e[1], e[2], ... and f[1], f[2], ... then the answer will be p[1]^max(0, e[1] - f[1]) * p[2]^max(0, e[2] - f[2]) ... . This is somehow mathematical but that should be the solution.

For example N = 120, M = 18.

N can be written as 2^3 * 3^1 * 5 and M can be written as 2^1 * 3^2. Now our solution will be 2^(3-1) * 5 which is equal to 20.

Edit:

The reason behind this, why this works is because of the following observations. If you jump to a place that has already been visited, then it must be 0. So we are trying to find the minimum value x such that x * m = 0 (mod n). I described how to find x by considering the prime factors. Implementation is left as an exercise.

Comment: Awesome! I tried for hours to remember this solution.

Comment: According to your example, I think you interverted the roles of `f` and `e`. Shouldn't it be max(0,e[i] - f[i]) ?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it seems correct but I don't fully understand this. Why do you state that `If you jump to a place that has already been visited, then it must be 0`. ?

Comment: It was a very intuitive assumption, sorry for not clarifying it. In my mind, if we start from any point a, and go to b, to c and so on we will have a->b->c->... ->a and we will arrive at a again and this cycle starts again. So that's why I guess a (or 0) will be the place where we will visit again.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit cleaner like this.

```
public int solution(int N, int M) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(N);
    int m = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    while(set.add(m)) {
       m = (m + M) % N ;
       ans++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: performance is not improved

Comment: I don't think you can do much better for very high values of N... unless you do some math to find a trick. This is out of the scope of your question.